# Abstracting Core Data Fetch Request

Tags: swift, core-data

```
func fetchRequestFromViewContext(nameOfEntity: NSManagedObject) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<nameOfEntity>(entityName: "\(nameOfEntity)")
    do {
        let result = try? CoreDataStack.instance.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    }
}
```

Trying to abstract the core data fetch request therefore making an argument of type managed object and passing it into the fetch request generic but is not letting me, am I on the right track on abstracting this core data fetch request?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add dome details about _but is not letting me_. Do you get some error message? How do you use it?

Comment: `NSFetchRequest` is already generic. You can improve abstraction dramatically by adding a protocol extension with class methods to be able to write something like `Entity.fetch(predicate: NSPredicate)` and get the proper subclass type back.

Answer (score 1):

`NSFetchRequest(entityName:)` takes a `String` but `nameofEntity` was given as an `NSManagedObject`. Change that to a `String` and then also pass in the type of the entity. You can use generics (the `<T>` below) to allow for any class conforming to `NSManagedObject`.

```
func fetchRequestFromViewContext<T: NSManagedObject>(nameOfEntity: String, type: T.Type) {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: nameOfEntity)
    do {
        let result = try? CoreDataStack.instance.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    }
}
```

To call this you would simply do:

```
fetchRequestFromViewContext(nameOfEntity: "YourEntity", type: YourEntity.self)
```

Comment: Thank you so much can I also abstract the managed objectcontext?

Comment: @Jagermeiste Yes you can create a class that takes the managed object context in the initializer, such as `DataManager(context: NSManagedObjectContext)`. Then when you call it you pass in the context you want to use.